# Python ValueError is it possible to get the Incorrect Value without string parsing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling, valueerror

I have this bit of code :

```
while True:
    
    try:
        start = int(input("Starting number: "))
        fin = int(input("Ending number: "))
        amount = int(input("Count by: "))
    
    except ValueError as verr:
        
        print('error : ', verr,'\n restarting ....')
        
    else:
        
        break
```

I would like to intercept the inputing of `''` just hitting `return` as a signal to exit the loop inside the `except` block. Is there any way to get the value that raises the  ValueError (I dont know how int() is able to return a ValueError and dont know about the latter either) other than parsing the ValueError `__repr__` , for example :

`invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'èèè'`  or the one I want to intercept

`invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save the input value before the conversion and use that to check.

```
while True:
    
    try:
        _start = _fin = _amount = None
        start = int(_start:=input("Starting number: "))
        fin = int(_fin:=input("Ending number: "))
        amount = int(_amount:=input("Count by: "))
    
    except ValueError as verr:
        if _start == "" or _fin == "" or _amount == "":
            break
        print('error : ', verr,'\n restarting ....')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I appreciate your answers but was hoping somebody could enlighten me about how the error is passed from int() on and if there is a way to write something like verr.@[@@[◘ to get the string representing the wrong inputted data

Comment: @pippo1980 - `int` raises a `ValueError` that you catch as `verr`. The information it contains is all you get. You could parse the error message (`verr.args[0]`) to pull out the value. That runs the risk of the error message changing and breaking your code. Its been stable for a long time, but then again, there is a lot of performance work going on in the code base right now and who knows if it will get fiddled with. Otherwise, you need some intermediate thing that saves the raw input before the conversion, and that's what I did with the walrus operator.

Comment: @pippo1980ONSTRIKE this solution assigns the original return value from `input(...)` to `_start` etc. It is the only way. The answer to "is it possible to" is _"no"_  - using a second variable like above is the best way around it, using `.split` like @bloodsexmagik suggested is the second best option.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would just get the inputs as strings then put an if statement to catch the case of `''` or whatever else before converting to `int` and catching `ValueErrors`. This might offend if you are a stickler for concise code though.

Or as you say, parse the **repr** with something like `.split(':')[-1]`

Comment: I appreciate your answers but was hoping somebody could enlighten me about how the error is passed from int() on and if there is a way to write something like verr.@[@@[◘ to get the string representing the wrong inputted data

Answer (score 2):

Since the error is raised without passing the function argument and is formatted as string, there is no way to get the value directly from the error, what you can do is store it separately as a variable and then check the variable directly like so:

```py
while True:
    data = {"start": 0, "fin": 0, "amount": 0}
    try:
        for i in data:
            x = input(f"Enter the value for {i}")
            x = int(x)
            data[i] = x
    except ValueError:
        if x == "":
            break
```

Comment: I was busy typing it out did not realize peeps have posted similar answers :p

Answer (score 2):

Others have already posted possible solutions for your problem but to answer your question directly.

**Question**: Python ValueError is it possible to get the Incorrect Value without string parsing?

**Answer**: No it is not. ValueError only stores a message string and nothing else. You can get that message by `str(verr)` or `verr.args[0]`. The `int(...)` call already creates the full message and doesn't pass it's input string seperatly to the `ValueError` in any way. :/